# window.open(url) not opening new web page in the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

`window.open("index.php");` does not open the new page in the *same* tab, it opens it in a *new* tab.

I tried `window.open("index.php",'_self')` as well which does not open the tab at all.

Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : "username="+name+"&password="+pwd ,
    datatype :"text",
    async: false, 
    cache: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    error: function() {
        return true;
    },
    success: function(msg) {                        

       if(msg == "Validated")
        {
            alert(msg);
            window.open("index.php");
        }
        if(msg=="Incorrect password")
        {
            alert(msg);
            location.reload();                         
        }    
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the whole point of `window.open()` - to open a **new window**.  If you want to update the current tab, just set `window.location.href` to your URL.

Comment: i have tried this ..... window.location.href for somereason does not work for me .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002938/go-to-a-new-page-using-only-jquery-and-not-java-script

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` to a new value works for everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `window.open` you should use `window.location = "http://...."`

Comment: not able to debug why window.location = url does not work ..... have also tried window.location.href ..... and using google chrome browser

Comment: You should add a "/" to your URL in order to make it relative, like this:     `window.location = "/index.php";`

Answer (score 2):

The `window.open` function opens a **new** window(or tab). The `window.location` changes the url the **current** tab.

Answer (score 1):

window.location is the function/property you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` will open in new tab if action is synchronous and invoked by user. If you remove `async: false` from ajax options (and this method is invoked by user for example by clicking a button), then new window will open instead of new tab. For simple navigation set `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `window.location` doesn't do this. The right method to do this is:

```
document.location = 'url-you-want-to-open.ext';
```

Best thing is to either include the full path (if it's on a different domain) or the absolute path if it's on the same domain. Only use relative path if the destination document is in the same folder.

To add to this:

`window` = speaks to the browser and its tabs

`document` = speaks to the current document that's loaded in the browser / tab.

Comment: `window.location` is correct and cross platform, `document.location` is supported by most browsers but not guaranteed. In browsers that support `document.location` they both have the exact same functionality.